# SQLite storing default timestamp as unixepoch

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

When defining a relation, I want to update an attribute to the timestamp at insert. For example, a working table that I have right now

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
time TIMESTAMP
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
txt TEXT);
```

This is updating a timestamp on insert, for example, `insert into t1 (txt) values ('hello')` adds the row `1|2012-07-19 08:07:20|hello|`. However, I want to have this date formatted in unixepoch format.

I read the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) but this wasn't clear. For example, I modified the table relation to `time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT DATETIME('now','unixepoch')` but I get an error. Here, as in the docs, `now` was my time string and `unixepoch` was the modifier but it didn't work. Could someone help me how to format it as a unixepoch timestamp?

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT` is not necessary for the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `strftime`:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%s', 'now');
1342685993
```

Use it in `CREATE TABLE` like this:

```
sqlite> create table t1 (
   ...> id integer primary key,
   ...> time timestamp default (strftime('%s', 'now')),
   ...> txt text);
sqlite> insert into t1 (txt) values ('foo');
sqlite> insert into t1 (txt) values ('bar');
sqlite> insert into t1 (txt) values ('baz');
sqlite> select * from t1;
1|1342686319|foo
2|1342686321|bar
3|1342686323|baz
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#tablecoldef

> If the default value of a column is an expression in parentheses, then the expression is evaluated once for each row inserted and the results used in the new row.

Comment: I tried this with `ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyTS timestamp default (strftime('%s', 'now'));` and got error "Cannot add a column with non-constant default"

Answer (score 22):

Note 'timestamp' is not a data type known to SQLite (see list [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).  The default value generated by strftime() would actually be stored as Text.

If it is important to store the value as a number instead of as a string, declare the field as an Integer and add a CAST() into the mix, like so:

```
create table t1(
...
ts_field integer(4) default (cast(strftime('%s','now') as int)),
...
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed strftime, which can also be used like so:

```
SELECT strftime('%s', timestamp) as timestamp FROM ... ;
```

Gives you:

> 1454521888

'timestamp' table column can be a text field even, using the `current_timestamp` as DEFAULT.

Without strftime:

```
SELECT timestamp FROM ... ;
```

Gives you:

> 2016-02-03 17:51:28